# How can I use an AJAX rpc call within a web part?

Tags: 2010, web-services, asp.net, ajax

I have a SharePoint 2010 web part on a page in a site. I'm trying to use AJAX to call my C# cs method to retrieve data, so I can display it in the web part.

I did have an example below, however, it returns the page default.aspx, instead of the result of 2 (within the function).

Here's my code:

```
//webpart.ascx.cs
[WebMethod]
public static int calculate(string name)
{
   Console.Write(name);
   int result = 1 + 1;
   return result;
}

//webpart.ascx
(function ($) {        
    var url = "/Pages/default.aspx/calculate"
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { name: "testing" },
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

How can I call an AJAX call within the web part (SharePoint with .ascx file)?

Thanks.

Comment: you can always use the CEWP to inject the javascript, no need to house it in it's own ascx

Answer (score 0):

> You cant add a WebMethod to a webpart.  A webpart is a server control
>   and outputs html to the page.  If you want to use webmethods I would
>   create a web service and consume this in the webpart or by other pages
>   / controls

But you can create an Application Page (like `WebMethods.aspx`).
Something like this:

```
using System.Web.Services;
public partial class WebMethods : LayoutsPageBase
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static int calculate(string name)
    {
        //Console.Write(name);
        int result = 1 + 1;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Use one of this urls:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/14/<project name folder>/<pagename>.aspx/<webmethod>"
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/14/<pagename>.aspx/<webmethod>"
```

Replace `<project name folder>` with your folder name. This is optional, it depends on where you position the page within your visual studio project structure.
Replace `<pagename>` with your page name.
Replace `<webmethod>` with your web method name.

And make the call like this:

```
//webpart.ascx
(function ($) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/14/<project name folder>/WebMethods.aspx/calculate"
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { name: "testing" },
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```